# How to upload php or html file in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

How to upload php or html file in codeigniter using upload library? I have controller which working ok when uploading  jpg, gif, png files but it won't to upload files with php or html or sql extension.

Here is my controller

```
public function ipload()
{
 $this->load->helper('url');
 $this->load->model('m_company');

 $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
 $config['allowed_types']        = 'php|html|txt';
 $config['max_size']             = 2048;
 $config['max_width']             = 0;
 $config['max_height']             = 0;

 $this->load->library('upload', $config);

 if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
 {
   $data = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
 }
 else
 {
   $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
   $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
   $filen = $this->upload->data('file_name');
   $this->m_company->set_doc($filen);
 }
echo json_encode($data);
 }
```

When allowed files are jpg gif png everything works fine

Comment: Have you tried setting the allowed_types as an array?  It's an alternative to a piped string, and shouldn't make a difference, but there might be an issue with the upload library.  Also, which version of CodeIgniter is it for?

Comment: I tried now to set as array and it works only for jpg, not for php, html, txt ...files. CI_version is 3.0.6. I didn't mentioned that do_upload not throwing  error message nor upload data

Answer (score 0):

first you setting controler, you can use access to upload file all class using 
 $config['allowed_types']   ='*';

```
class c_cutipegawai extends CI_Controller{
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
function do_upload(){
    $config['upload_path']      ='./upload/SuratCuti/';
    $config['allowed_types']    ='*';
    $config['max_size']         =1024*8;
    $config['max_widht']        =1024*2;
    $config['max_height']       =768;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if(! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    }
    else{
        $data=array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

    }
}
}
```

After setting in controler, now we craete view to insert button upload file

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>


<?php echo form_open_multipart('C_CutiPegawai/do_upload');?>

  <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

  <br /><br />

  <input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body> 
</html>
```